# How does Web SpeechRecognizer compare to Android/iOS SpeechRecognizer?

Tags: speech-recognition, speech-to-text, google-cloud-speech, webspeech-api, android-speech-api

If it would be to choose between `Web SpeechRecognizer` and `Android/iOS SpeechRecognizer`(mainly `Android` or mobile as a whole), what would be the advantages and disadvantages of both?

Criterias: offline/online recognition, languages support, processing speed, fidelity of the recognized text, continuous listening, limitations etc

Personal experience is appreciated as well:)

Comment: I would choose my own library for much greater flexibility than those two ;)